# Internacionalize Ext-js

Tags: javascript, internationalization, extjs

I'm doing a Ext-js application, I don't know how to internacionalize it.

How to do it?

I should read a .txt file that contains different strings? How to do it...?

Comment: I found it: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Localizing_Ext

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it so that it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

We're using gettext[1]-like localization. All language-dependent strings are wrapped in `tr()` (like `var msg = tr('SERVER_ADDRESS');`).

`tr` itself looks like this:

```
function tr(msg)
{
    if (!_translation[msg]) {
        return msg;
    }
    return _translation[msg];
}
```

gettext `po`-files are converted to javascript code like this:

```
_translation = {
    SERVER_ADDRESS: 'The server address'
};
```

And this file is included as regular javascript source file.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext